# SQL foreign keys

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I was create tables with the syntax in phpmyadmin:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS info;

CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id int unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  email varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  pwd varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  isAdmin int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (user_id)
) TYPE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE info (
  info_id int unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  first_name varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  last_name varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  address varchar(300) NOT NULL default '',
  zipcode varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  personal_phone varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  mobilephone varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  faxe varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  email2 varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  country varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  sex varchar(1) NOT NULL default '',
  birth varchar(1) NOT NULL default '',

  email varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (info_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES users(email) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) TYPE=INNODB;
```

But shows the error:

> "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=INNODB' at line 11 "

If I remove the TYPE=INNODB in the end of create the tables, it will show the error:

> "#1005 - Can't create table 'curriculo.info' (errno: 150) ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ENGINE = INNODB`,  not `TYPE = InnoDB`.

From MySQL docs, version 5.1, [`CREATE TABLE` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html):

> **Note**
>
> The older `TYPE` option was synonymous with `ENGINE`. `TYPE` **has been deprecated** since MySQL 4.0 but is still supported for backward compatibility in MySQL 5.1 (excepting MySQL 5.1.7). ***Since MySQL 5.1.8, it produces a warning***. **It is removed in MySQL 5.5**. You should not use `TYPE` in any new applications, and you should immediately begin conversion of existing applications to use ENGINE instead. (See Section D.1.64, “Changes in MySQL 5.1.8 (Not released)”.)

---

If you want to have this Foreign Key:

```
FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES users(email)
```

the `users(email)` should have a `UNIQUE` constraint. All Foreign Keys should reference either a Primary or a Unique Key. You want a row in the `info` table to reference (through the FK) one and only one user (row in the users table).

---

Best practise though (for various reasons) is to have narrow (small) and constant-wide columns as Foreign Keys. Your `email` is 100 characters which could be from 100 to 300 bytes (depending on the charset). So, you may consider using `user_id` as the FK, which is just 4 bytes wide:

```
CREATE TABLE info (
  ...
             ---- email varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',   
             ---- removed
  user_id int unsigned NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY  (info_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id)
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) TYPE=INNODB;
```

Comment: If I did not specify the engine he takes it by default. But the error "#1005 - Can't create table 'curriculo.info' (errno: 150) " continues.

Comment: Probably because you don't have a `UNIQUE KEY (email)` in the `users` table.

Answer (score 2):

Try "Engine=INNODB" at the end of the create. (not TYPE)

If you don't have it, it might not work as it depends on your default Engine type in the mysql preferences... MyIsam (the most common default engine) does not support foreign keys.

Comment: I execute the command "show table status;" and it was shown that the type is INNODB.

Comment: try: show create table <table_name> and that might give you more information.  Not sure why mysql confuses Type and Engine in this case.. but if you check out: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html  you will see  the Engine keyword in there.

Comment: shows "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1" but continue with the error ""#1005 - Can't create table 'curriculo.info' (errno: 150) " witch I think its a foreign error,